Prove that pair of coprime integer can be written as element-wise sum of two pairs of coprime integers
My question is as follows: let $x,y$ be positive and comprime. Then do there necessarily exist $(a,b)$ coprime and $(c,d)$ coprime such that $x=a+c, y=b+d$, where $a,b,c,d> 0$?
For example, consider $x=45, y=8$. Then $(45,8)=(17,3)+(28,5)$, where $\gcd(17,3)=\gcd(28,5)=1$.
I've checked experimentally with Python and it seems to always be true, but I'm having trouble proving it. Any insight is helpful, thank you.

Not following.  For any $n$, we have $n=1+(n-1)$ and $\gcd(1, n-1)=1$.  We don't need $\gcd(x,y)=1$.

@lulu I'm sorry I'm confused about your confusion. Can you clarify? EDIT: sorry I messed up the place of a,b,c,d. I've corrected it. Hopefully it is clear now.

Yes, that clarifies the question.

But you can still take $x=1+(x-1)$ and $y=(y-1)+1$ or, in your notation, $(x,y)=(1, y-1)+(x-1, 1)$.  Again, nothing to do with $\gcd(x,y)$.

@JohnOmielan You are right, I should've set x>1 and y>1. It does not work if x=1 and y=1.
